# How do I use the collision detection (in ActionScript 3.0) on one side of a rectangle differently then the others sides

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been trying to fiqure out how to use the collision detection on one side of a rectangle differently then the other sides. for example: Mario mashes boxes with his head, by standing under the box and jumping up. (I'm refering to just the Super Mario Bros. game). If Mario hits the box from the sides or top nothing will break or come out of the box. How do you do that in Actionscript 3.0.

I been use the following code for my objects that have colllision detection.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,hitTest);

function hitTest(evt:Event):void
{
  if(object1.hitTestPoint(object2.x,object2.y,true))
  {

  }
  else
  {

  }
}
```

let say Mario is object2, and the box is object1.  How do I collide with one side of the box differently then the other sides.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to test to see if the `y` of Mario is greater than the lowest point of the rectangle's bounding box. You can get the bounding box using [getBounds](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29). I believe that the resulting value's y + its height will be the bottom of the box you seek.

Comment: This solution is better than mine, but I'm leaving mine up for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a thin rectangle along the bottom of the block and detect collision against that when there is a collision on the block.